# How to manage CI/CD for custom container Azure functions with ACR

Tags: azure, azure-devops, cloud, devops, azure-function-app

I'm working with Azure functions and ACR (azure container registry) to deploy a custom docker image, when I'm deploying for the first time, it works, with `az functionapp create` command, but the function will not update for the image, unless I give each image a unique tag, ie. digest is not enough.

For example:

```
* build 1 (digest: hash-xxx1)
my-image:dev => deploy => deployed properly

* made changes and added a new build (digest: hash-xxx2)
my-image:dev => deploy => stays on the first build

* changed the tag completely
my-image:${Build.Id} => deploy => deployed properly
```

But now I'm stuck with a lot of tagged images and they consume a lot of space in ACR - and there is no way to safely remove them automatically.

I tried changing the build ID, and I tried any command of `az functionapp` like `update` and `set container` with no success.

I have no errors, but the image in the function app won't update unless I give each image a unique tag - which makes the ACR bloated.

Comment: I have been trying to get my docker image (in my ACR) to run on my new Azure Function App. Since you already seem to have figured out this part, can you please tell me what I am doing wrong::

az functionapp config container set -i myPrototype.azurecr.io/myproto:latest -n AzPrototypeFunction --resource-group AzPrototype

The above cli command is not working for me. I am running this after I have created the function app. If I were to integrate this into the az functionapp create command, how should it be?
Thank you in advance